# What XML serialization method should I use for a public API?

Tags: c#, .net, datacontractserializer, xmlserializer, ixmlserializable

I'm writing a program that builds up a tree structure made up of classes that inherit from an abstract `Node` class. There are a number of different type of nodes built into my program. However, I also want to allow more advanced users to be able to reference my library and write their own derivations of `Node`. These plug-in libraries are then loaded when my app starts up through `Assembly.Load()`. Thus all the potential `Node` types used by my application will not be known until run time.

In addition, I want to be able to serialize and deserialize these trees to and from XML files. I have some experience with XMLSerializer, DataContractSerializer, and implementing IXmlSerializable. Typically, I go with DataContractSerializer as it usually requires less code then implementing IXmlSerializable, and can serialize private fields where XmlSerializer can not.

Yet with this project I also have to consider that other users will be creating classes that derive from my class, and will also have to add whatever code or attributes are required to serialize them as well.

Considering this are there reasons I should go with one serialization mechanism over another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the serialization and deserialization will only occur within your application, and if there is no requirement that anyone else be able to read the serialized data, then the serialization format doesn't impact the API: as far as a user of the API is concerned, you will serialize into an opaque file and deserialize from the same.

In this case, use DataContractSerializer, as it can serialize into binary if necessary.

Comment: Yes I don't see any reason why any program other then my program would need to serialize/deserialize these files, and I also like the idea of allowing for other serialization formats, such as binary, in the future.

Comment: To be clear, the "binary" I meant is the binary-serialized XML that the XmlDictionaryWriter class can emit. We're all used to text-serialized XML, but that's just a serialization format.